# Find out how app is pulling data from server so the same request can be done from webapp or other application

Tags: java, android, web-services, http, servlets

How can I find out exactly what type of request to a server is being made from an android app that I am using so I can replicate such a request outside of the app usage.

Specifically I am using the home depot app that has a bar code scanner.It also has a manual barcode number input.

The manual bar code input search is what I am interested in replicating for use in a webapp.

I assume it is just a server request with the appropriate information that the server responds to.

How might I start figuring this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local proxy for your device. For example this one: http://www.charlesproxy.com